# If fclose() fails, is the file descriptor still open?

Tags: c, posix, fclose

Imagine the following code running as a thread:

```c
void *thread_worker(void *q) {
 for (;;) {
  int fd = some_queue_get(q);
  FILE *writer = fdopen(fd, "w");
  if (!writer) { perror("fdopen"; close(fd); continue; }
  // do something with writer

  if (fclose(writer) == EOF) {
   perror("fclose writer");
   // should fd be closed here?
   close(fd);
  }
}
```

`fclose(3)` can fail for various reasons - is there a guarantee that/when the underlying file descriptor is closed or that it is still open afterwards?

- if fd is not closed by fclose on a flushing failure, one leaks fds without an additional close.
- if fd is closed by fclose, an additional close might close a file descriptor that was newly opened by an other thread.

Comment: From the doc: if  fclose failed, any further access (including another call to fclose) to the       stream results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jabberwocky i don't want to access the stream, but the file descriptor

Comment: Given the name of your function - `thread_worker`, `close(fd)` is ***dangerous***.  If `fclose()` did close its file descriptor but failed anyway, another thread could reuse that value and you'd close it right out from under that other thread.

Comment: @AndrewHenle As thejonny wrote in the last sentence...

Comment: @Thomas And there's really no way to check for that condition.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes, that's why i asked this question - is there a way to be sure

Comment: @thejonny: If you are using an OS which doesn't guarantee that close deallocates the FD, then you'll just have to live with the possibility of a leaked file descriptor. You *must not* retry `fclose` after failure, nor may you attempt to `close` the underlying FD. Fortunately, you are unlikely to be using such an OS. For example, "the Linux kernel always releases the file descriptor early in the close operation, freeing it for reuse; the steps that may return an error, such as flushing data to the filesystem or  device, occur only later in the close operation." (from man close)

Comment: Or, from man close on freebsd: "In case of any error except EBADF, the supplied file descriptor is deallocated and therefore is no longer valid." (This will also be the case on OS X, afaik.)

Comment: I might move those comments to an answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man fclose` does not provide the answer on my system either, but `man 3p fclose` reveals the [official version from the POSIX Programmer's manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3p.html), which is much more comprehensive on the matter:

> The `fclose()` function shall perform the equivalent of a `close()` on the file descriptor that is associated with the stream pointed to by stream.

Comment: But [`close()` can fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114152/what-to-do-if-a-posix-close-call-fails) and there's nothing you can do about it other than log it.  In particular, you ***can't*** safely retry the `close()` call.

Comment: this also matches the current glibc behaviour, but not the first glibc source if found googling (an ancient version) :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **NO**, the C Standard is ambiguous about this (emphasis mine):

> **7.21.5.1 The `fclose` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int fclose(FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> **Description**
> A successful call to the `fclose` function causes the stream pointed to by `stream` to be flushed and the associated file to be closed. Any unwritten buffered data for the stream are delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; any unread buffered data are discarded. *Whether or not the call succeeds, the stream is disassociated from the file and any buffer set by the `setbuf` or `setvbuf` function is disassociated from the stream (and deallocated if it was automatically allocated).*
>
> **Returns**
> The `fclose` function returns zero if the stream was successfully closed, or `EOF` if any errors were detected.

Comment: The C standard is irrelevant since file descriptors are not a standard C concept. You need to look at some POSIX/Unix specification/implementation to know the effect of `fclose` on file descriptors.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': It would be perverse to implement *the stream is disassociated from the file* by discarding the `FILE` structure while keeping the associated file descriptor open.  Yet there is a more general issue: `close()` can fail for a reason that I have never seen anybody handle even in production code. If it is interrupted by a signal, `close()` fails, `errno` is set to `EINTR` and the file descriptor is still open.